# Windows not loading after Dual Booting windows 10 & ubuntu 15

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I am a complete Newbie to Ubuntu. I had Windows 10 upgraded from Windows 7. I dual booted it with Ubuntu 15, by selecting "Something else" in the installation menu, later creating partitions for Ubuntu. Everything went successfully. I got Ubuntu 15 installed. When I re-started, on boot menu when I select Windows 10, It dosent boot. A black screen comes for 2 seconds and again the boot menu comes infront. But when Ubuntu is selcted it runs smoothly. When I tried to access partitions of Windows through Ubuntu, it shows this message:-

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/aks/3EAA6FCBAA6F7E71: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/aks/3EAA6FCBAA6F7E71"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I DID TYPE `fdisk -l` in terminal and it shows:
[image: Terminal]

Please tell me a breif descriptions with Codes(if necessary), to access files on Windows. Or to make access to Windows via boot.
It is too much necessary as my Very important documents are in Windows and I can't access them.

Somebody please help. :)

Comment: Run the command `fdisk -l` and then [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: You shutdown Windows via pulling the power, or using the Vulcan nerve pinch. The Windows disk is in an inconsistent state. The closed source nature of Windows makes it difficult to impossible for a Linux tool to fix the disk structure. Boot Windows, use Windows tools to fix the disk, then shutdown Windows politely, so Windows and ensure that the disk is happy.

Comment: @waltinator..i am unable to boot into windows. Whenever we select Windows on boot menu, it again comes the boot menu but windows dosent open. I have access only to Ubuntu

Comment: @CarlH..I have update the question with Output. Please check

Comment: You may have left Windows always on hibernation or fast start on. Grub will not boot it, nor LInux mount it if hibernated. You need to directly boot Windows and turn off fast start. If UEFI you can choose Windows from UEFI boot menu, not grub menu. IF BIOS you may have to temporarily reinstall Windows boot loader to MBR. Duplicate of : http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: You may have a cross-mode installation (Windows in EFI/UEFI mode and Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, or vice-versa), but I can't be sure of that. Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) in Ubuntu. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. That will give us detailed information we need to make a diagnosis rather than a guess.

Answer (score 0):

To access files on Windows, you can mount your Windows partition with read-only privilege. eg.

`sudo mkdir /media/windows`

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/windows`

This works for me on my Windows 10 & Ubuntu 15.10 dual booting system.

To enter into Windows 10, you should check your boot sequences in bios settings by selecting Windows UEFI boot method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the recovery disk(USB) for Windows 10? I will suggest do a fresh install of both the O/S. First recover the system and install(recover) Windows 10. Then create partitions for Ubuntu from Windows only(using disk management tool).
Make sure secure boot is completed disabled in BIOS. If windows 10 is installed in EFI mode, make sure that Ubutnu is also installed in EFI mode only.
Now make use of the live USB to install Ubuntu. At the time of install options - choose install Ubuntu along side Windows(I don't recommend something else option for newbies). Once the installation is done - make sure that grub2 is working. In case not, use boot-repair and follow the steps. All this is not that difficult if you read the instructions and follow askubuntu and ubuntuforums properly. Best of luck.